# Spotify - how to authorize for new-releases

Tags: spotify

I have som questions about the Spotify web api endpoint **/v1/browse/new-releases**.

I want to list new Spotify releases on my site for my users to see. I don't want any details from my users about their spotify account.

For my site i have created a application over at Spotify developer and i have a client ID, client Secret and a redirect uri.

Which of the three Authorization methods will best suite my needs?

Thanx
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Client Credentials](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) oAuth flow is best suited since you don't need a user's permission to make requests to this endpoints. The other flows, [Authorization Code](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) flow and [Implicit Grant](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow) flow, both require a user's permission to retrieve an access token.

Comment: Thank you Michael. This means that i first have to get a access token right?

Comment: Yes, an access token is required to use the Get New Releases endpoint.

Comment: One last question then i think. For getting the access token i need to apply "code", what is code?

Comment: Do you mean `code` as part of the Authorization Code flow? You don't need to use a code as part of the Client Credentials flow - it's documented in the link provided in the answer.